# C++ conversion from array to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, conventions

I am bit struggling with kinda easy task. I need to convert array to pointer.

```
GLfloat serieLine[8][80];

GLfloat *points = &serieLine[0][0];
```

this gives me just first value, but how can I get all values in the array?

Comment: I don't understand: `serieLine` _is_ a pointer.

Comment: @sturmer: You might not quite understand that `serieLine` is **not** a pointer.

Comment: @sturmer: No it's not; it's an array (of arrays).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Charles, Vanya: sorry, my bad; I checked around and learned something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want pointer to an array, you can do it like this:

```
GLfloat (*points)[80] = serieLine;
```

`points` will point to the first row of `serieLine`. If you increment `points`, it will point to the next row.

Answer (score 3):

Increment the pointer, and it'll point at the next value in the array (so once you've incremented it 8*80 times you'll have seen all of the values)

Comment: The C++ standard is remarkably vague as to whether this would be legal. See [expr.add].